# Unexpected Behaviour After Change Account Name in AD

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, user-accounts

We have an issue with SharePoint 2016 on 2 accounts created in AD. We have 2 users, i.e. user1 and user2 which have been created in AD and sync to the SharePoint. After a while, the 2 account name have been swapped in AD so the AD accounts ended up like:

- user1 -> user2
- user2 -> user1

We found that SharePoint seems to confuse the 2 users and when user2 (originally user1) login, the SharePoint seems to think that user1 is logged and some of our custom webparts did not work because it failed to map the correct user. SharePoint returned the login name of the user2 is i:0#.w|domain\user1 instead of the supposed i:0#.w|domain\user2. Are there anyways to fix these 2 accounts? Thanks

Update:
We found a strange behaviour with the user profile for user1 and user2. After we did a user profile import from AD, the user profile is able to show in the User Profile Application in Central Admin. Then after the User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization timer jobs has run, the profile become corrupted, i.e. the user2 email became empty (which was not in AD and before the sync job) and user1 disappear completely from the user profile. We suspect there is something wrong with the SPUser objects for user1 and user2 in all the site collections but we do not know how to check or confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to clear the browser cache and log in the user in inprivite mode.

If the issue persists, please append the following URL to the site to delete the conflicting user from the site collection, grant the user again to compare the result.

```
_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0
```

-----------------------------Update--------------------------------

Please check the display name of user in AD, after login, it will show display name of the user, not the account name:

[image]

Comment: We tried removing the users but the issue still persist. The SharePoint sites still think the user2 is user1.

Comment: I have updated the reply, please check it.

Comment: We checked in AD and the display name is correct, i.e. user2. We found some strange behaviour with the user profile in central admin and updated my original post.

Comment: User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization performs a full synchronization of the user information from the (UPA to the SharePoint users. It also synchronizes site memberships from SharePoint to the UPA every hour.)For your issue, please make sure user1 and user 2 both in AD, delete users in site first, run full sync again to compare the result.

Comment: We tried to delete the user in the site but the issue still persist. We delete the user by removing the user in the SharePoint UI. Is it the correct way to delete the user or are there any other recommended ways? Thanks

Comment: Ways to delete user in site collection,after deleting, run a full sync in user profile:https://www.brightwork.com/blog/how-to-remove-a-user-completely-from-a-site-collection